# Undefined Control Sequence but same cls \maketitle

Tags: titles

I'm having that problem when creating the title of my thesis. I know it is because the command created in the .cls file is different from the declarations I'm using in the .tex file, but I can't find the problem. Here's my .tex part:

```
\title{\Large{title}}
\crest{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{Figures/...}}
\author{My Name}
\collegeordept{Dept}
\university{Uni Name}

\supervisor{Supervisor name}
% DECLARATION
% Use the following command to change the declaration text:
%\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{INSERT NEW TEXT HERE}
\degree{Master's degree}
\degreedate{Date}

\begin{document}

% A page with the abstract and running title and author etc may be
% required to be handed in separately. If this is not so, comment
% the following 3 lines:
% \begin{abstractseparate}
%   \input{Abstract/abstract}
% \end{abstractseparate}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\maketitle
\end{spacing}
```

And the .cls part:

```
% TITLE PAGE
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\pagenumbering{roman} % Sasa Tomic
\setcounter{page}{0}  % Sasa Tomic
\begin{alwayssingle}
  \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
  \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
%  \null\vfill
\begin{center}
  { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
  {\large \vspace*{30mm} {{\@crest} \par} \vspace*{20mm}}
  {{\Large \@author} \par}
  {\large \vspace*{1ex}
  {{\@collegeordept} \par}
  \vspace*{1ex}
  {{\@university} \par}
  \vspace*{20mm}
  {{\submittedtext} \par}
  \vspace*{1ex}
  {\it {\@degree} \par}
  \vspace*{2ex}
  {\@degreedate}}
 \end{center}
%     \null\vfill
 \end{alwayssingle}
}
```

Where am I wrong? Thank you all.

Edit: the error is

```
\maketitle ... } \vspace *{20mm} {{\submittedtext 
                                              } \par } \vspace *{1ex} 
{\...
l.109 \maketitle
            
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Please show a complete document that can be used to reproduce your problem. Also paste the exact error message if there is any.

Comment: Added the link to my documents

Comment: Note that links to mwe is usually frowned upon here as the question is likely to not be usable in the future as the external files are no longer available

Comment: @daleif Which has happened now. The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The `.cls` defines

```
\newcommand{\submittedtextt}{{\textit{Supervisor}}}
```

yet the `\maketitle` uses

```
\submittedtext
```

You need to fix the `.cls` to define

```
\newcommand{\submittedtext}{{\textit{Supervisor}}}
```

Comment: Perfect, the error is gone! But now, whenever I try to add the supervisor name in \supervisor, when compiles it doesn't print the supervisor name. Here's the new .cls:`\newcommand{\submittedtext}{{\textit{Supervisor}}}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\def\@supervisor{#1}}` and the .tex: `\supervisor{supervisor name}`. How do I fix this?

Comment: @thranduil90: That's because `\@supervisor` - the macro that stores your supervisor name - is never used within `\maketitle`. So, you can define it all you want but it won't appear anywhere unless you update `\maketitle` to use it.

Comment: I have added the following code:       `{\Large {\@supervisor} \par}
      \vspace*{1ex}` to the \makefile in the .cls, and in the .tex I added: `  \supervisor{name}` after the   \university but I'm getting the error on \maketitle again. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @thranduil90: What error?

Comment: Same as before, the one in the original post

Comment: @thranduil90: You need to save the `.cls` so that it can be used. Can you post the `.log` somewhere (like on [PasteBin](//pastebin.com))?

Comment: here's the log on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/5yJ16f8q

Comment: @thranduil90: Did you change the `\newcommand{\submittedtextt}{.}` to `\newcommand{\submittedtext}{.}`?

Comment: yes, I did. But I don's understand where I'm wrong

Comment: @thranduil90: Okay, well, in order to understand where you're at, I need to be able to reproduce the problem. You'll have to post your full code somewhere.